# Outlook Add-in: Taskpane suddenly closing on folder items change in OWA

Tags: outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I’m working on an add-in for Microsoft Outlook, and I’ve noticed a strange taskpane behavior in the Outlook Web App.  To reproduce this issue:

1. Open a mailbox folder (“Inbox” for example).
2. Start drafting a new email by clicking the “New” button.
3. Open the taskpane of any add-in.
4. Receive an email, or delete a message from the same folder from a different device/window.
5. The taskpane will suddenly close.

This behavior seems to happen anytime the mailbox content changes at all (for example, if you receive an email, or if a message is deleted).

Is this closing of the taskpane intentional?  I’ve noticed this new behavior only happens in the non-beta version of the Outlook Web App (not in Outlook 2016 or the beta version of the Outlook Web App).

This issue has been causing trouble for us in particular because we have a dialog that is opened from the taskpane; if the user receives an email while the dialog is opened, the taskpane closes and the open dialog cannot be closed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps and investigation. The bug is a known issue, and has been fixed in the new version of Outlook Web App. For the old version of Outlook Web App, we have a bug in our backlog, but no timeline to share currently.